# Golang GORM Cascade Delete to Nested Fields

Tags: go, go-gorm

##### Main Model:

```
 type Page struct {
        ID                  int                  `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
        Title               string               `gorm:"unique;not null" json:"title"`
        LocalizedPageTitles []LocalizedPageTitle `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"localizedPageTitles"`
        Paragraphs          []Paragraph          `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"paragraphs"`
        CreatedAt           time.Time            `json:"-"`
        UpdatedAt           time.Time            `json:"-"`
        DeletedAt           gorm.DeletedAt       `gorm:"index" json:"-"`
    }
```

###### First Child:

```
type Paragraph struct {
    ID                  uint                 `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    Text                string               `gorm:"unique;not null" json:"text"`
    PageID              uint                 `json:"pageId"`
    LocalizedParagraphs []LocalizedParagraph `gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"localizedParagraphs"`
    CreatedAt           time.Time            `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt           time.Time            `json:"-"`
    DeletedAt           gorm.DeletedAt       `gorm:"index" json:"-"`
}
```

###### Second Child:

```
type LocalizedParagraph struct {
    Localized
    ID          uint           `gorm:"primarykey" json:"id"`
    ParagraphID uint           `json:"paragraphId"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time      `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time      `json:"-"`
    DeletedAt   gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index" json:"-"`
}
```

This is how I delete my page entity:

```
func (p PageRepositoryImpl) Delete(id int) error {
    return p.db.Unscoped().Select(clause.Associations).Delete(&entity.Page{ID: id}).Error
}
```

Above function deletes `Page` and `Paragraphs` but how can I remove `LocalizedParagraphs` automatically?

By the way I'm using Sqlite.

**dbmanager.go**

```
func InitSQLite(filePath string) *gorm.DB {
    database, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open(filePath), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error:%v", err)
        panic("Failed to connect database")
    }
    autoMigrateDB(database)
    return database
}

func autoMigrateDB(db *gorm.DB) {
    db.AutoMigrate(
        &entity.Page{},
        &entity.Paragraph{},
        &entity.LocalizedPageTitle{},
        &entity.LocalizedParagraph{},
    )
}
```

Comment: I switched from Sqlite to PostgreSql but same behavior continues, It cascades one level but does not cascade for the second level.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't perform this action without [delete hooks](https://gorm.io/docs/delete.html#Delete-Hooks).
`Select(clause.Associations)` statement already take care of the one level associations:

```
func (p PageRepositoryImpl) Delete(id int) error {
    return p.db.Unscoped().Select(clause.Associations).Delete(&entity.Page{ID: id}).Error
}
```

For nested associations, I used delete hook,
here is my solution:

```
func (page *Page) BeforeDelete(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    paragraphs := make([]Paragraph, 0)
    err := tx.Where("page_id = ?", page.ID).Find(&paragraphs).Error
    if err != nil{
        return err
    }
    ids := make([]int, 0, len(paragraphs))
    for _, element := range paragraphs{
        ids = append(ids, int(element.ID))
    }
    lps := make([]LocalizedParagraph,0)
    err = tx.Where("paragraph_id IN ?", ids).Unscoped().Delete(&lps).Error
    return err;
    }
```